# how to make eclipse issue warnings when using methods added in api levels higher than minSdkVersion?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using SDK level 17 and have set

```
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"...
```

in my manifest.xml. On the other hand, in View class we have:

```
    // ADDED IN API LEVEL 16
    setBackground(...)
```

but when I use this method in my code, no warning is issued and the app crashes on devices running APIs lower than 16.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved via Lint.

*The lint tool checks your Android project source files for potential bugs and optimization improvements for correctness, security, performance, usability, accessibility, and internationalization. You can run lint from the command-line or from the Eclipse environment.*

---

**Configuring lint in Eclipse**

*You can configure `global`, `project-specific`, and `file-specific` settings for `lint` from the Eclipse user interface.*

***Global preferences***

1. Open `Window > Preferences > Android > Lint Error Checking`.
2. Specify your preferences and click OK.

These settings are applied by default when you run lint on your Android projects in Eclipse.

***For more details and Project and file-specific preferences, read [Lint documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html)***.